# Eevee: Light leaking into adjacent walled-off room

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with two rooms next to each other. On the left, there's a corridor with area lamps emitting light. However, that light is passing through into the adjacent room. I've tried using different light probes but there isn't enough insight on those yet for me to understand them.

**Example from inside corridor:**

*Green - light from area lamps*

*Red - incorrect passes into engine room*

[image]

**Example from inside adjacent room:**

*Green - light from area lamps*

*Red - incorrect passes into engine room*

*Yellow - light leakage*

[image]

Here's an outside view of the two rooms:

[image]

Is there a fix for this? I'm aware that this is only a beta and this may be a bug that is going to be patched, but I'm also aware I might be doing something wrong here. I appreciate any answers in advance!

[image]

Comment: I recently added an answer to a related question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131061/eevee-2-8-the-light-goes-through-the-egdes-of-a-simple-cube/131077#131077

Answer (score 1):

could have to do with this issue eevee is currently having with light https://developer.blender.org/T57752