# EEVEE 2.8 : the light goes through the egdes of a simple cube?

Tags: light, edges, eevee-render-engine

The scene : a simple cube with the front face deleted, and a simple light behind the cube.
The light could be seen inside the cube. It comes through the edges !
How to prevent this ? Thanks a lot !
Emmanuel
[image]

Comment: Have you tried Cycles rendering engine?

Comment: Yes, it is OK with Cycles. But I want to try eevee !

Answer (score 8):

Welcome Patrick!

Yes, there are a couple of ways to handle these problems in EEVEE.

Thicker geometry reduces the problem:

[image]

Increasing the Shadow Exponent value on the spotlight makes the fade shorter.

[image]

Adding contact shadows fills in the fade:

[image]

It should however be noted that Contact Shadows are created with the depth map and may create undesired artefacts. This could be handled in a single shot but if you render a sequence it might be harder.

The VSM shadows (In render settings) generates a bit noisier shadow gradient but should be hided with less geometry.

[image]

Or if you absolutely need to keep your geometry paper thin you could add a tiny contact shadow.

[image]

Here is where you find the settings:
[image][image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jackdaw, I tried it successfully !! Do you think this situation will change in the future ?

Comment: There are other ways that could complement the current solutions. It would be nice to be able to have ray traced shadows and/or baked shadows. I guess that it comes down to how many developers we can found.