# EVEE Lighting and Volume Scatter showing through walls

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows, volumetrics

I have a scene set up in EVEE with an object with a volume scatter material and a light on the outside. The light should only be coming through a window but there is volume being illuminated along the inside of the wall the light is shining on. Any ideas on how to fix it? Clamping volume in the render settings isn't working either.[image]

Comment: I am guessing this is happening because the volume extends outside the room, and in the process of rasterizing, the algorithm is counting pixels that intersect the light outside as lit, even though they also appear inside. To fix it, I might recommend faking the scene a little, or using cycles instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Eevee sometimes really has some troubles with volumetric lighting. As they say here: https://developer.blender.org/T71208

> I think this was a side effect of a previous bug (in 2.80). basically, the volumes were all shifted 1 voxel further from the camera. This was fixed but now this light leaking is just a side effect of the volume texture being low res.
> There is little we can do to fix it. The workaround is to give more precision to the volume (increase samples in volumetric settings) and the shadow maps.

> this is a sort of precision error.
> This probably won't be fixed anytime soon.
> Unless a new groundbreaking volumetric lighting approach is discovered, which is... quite unlikely? You can attempt to alleviate this by making the volumetric lighting texture more fine. This will however use more VRAM so be careful

I hope it will help.

These few quite similar cases may be helpful too:

- https://developer.blender.org/T61654
- https://blenderartists.org/t/why-spot-light-coming-throught-the-mesh/1227943
- [EEVEE 2.8 : the light goes through the egdes of a simple cube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131061/eevee-2-8-the-light-goes-through-the-egdes-of-a-simple-cube/131077#131077)