# Eevee - Irradiance volume and light baking in complex environment

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, baking, lightprobe

I am in the learning process of Blender, currently working on my own interior environment and I would like to use eevee for rendering. I have a problem with indirect light baking and irradiance volume (IV) in particular. Problem is that whatever I do, I am not able to get a satisfying result without shading issues, artifacts and sometimes spiky shading.

I watched numerous tutorials, problem is that all of them consider simple scenes such as plane, sphere and sunlight, or simple rectangular room with window and basic furniture, nothing really advanced. My interior is quite complex and it´s not shaped regularly, it includes some curved walls and numerous props. You can see the environment in attached pictures. Following one shows the best baking result so far but not good enough because it still has some artifacts and irregular light on the ground, particularly along the wall with light strip.
[image: Best result]
I spent 3 days and endless hours trying, doing bakes, different settings, different resolutions of IV, I tried one IV, more IVs for different parts of environment etc, unsuccessfully. I tried even some insane resolutions (50 by 50) but the result was shit, it was better with lower number of probes. With model like this, it is almost, if not completely impossible to place the volume without some probes being inside of geometry and causing problems. How would you solve this? Is it even possible? If I use more probes (higher resolution), I can´t avoid bugs, if I use less probes, diffuse light on the ground (mainly) looks bad. Sorry for long text but after so many unsuccessful attempts, I feel really desperate and I have no idea what to do. I also attached solid shading picture so you have idea about what my model looks like.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Eevee, even with its all glory, is fast because it fakes ... so it is limited in result for sure. If it is even possible to get some tips here, probably would be helpful if you can mark the issues or render in cycles for comparison. Speaking to Cycles ... with Denoise it is not such a big deal to work with, especially if your expectations for accuracy are high.

Comment: BTW your Q is quite wide ... you are probably risking closing your Q. Light leaking (one of many if you haven't seen yet) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131061 probably can be individually solved ... but irradiance for dome shape would be really challenge. Irradiance volume is based on rectangle grid that will never match even light distribution for spherical shape.